# Android Deep Linking not working with https

Tags: android, deep-linking

Android deep linking is not working with https..But it works with http .

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="www.test.uz" />

    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from github.com.

```
<data android:scheme="https"
    android:host="test.uz"/>
```

just removed www.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are adding  tag separately for **scheme** and **host** properties. 
You need to add  tag once and add both **scheme** and **host** properties. in the same tag.

**This is a valid way**.

**scheme** and **host** properties.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data android:scheme="http" 
        android:host="www.test.uz" />

</intent-filter>
```